# TensorFlow multi-GPU imbalance utilisation

Tags: tensorflow

[image]
I trained on 2 GPUs, each with a copy of model and variables. I inspect the run-time profile, both GPUs have the same number of computation blocks (though you see the length are different because GPU2 computes faster). But the GPU utilisation for GPU1 is 3 times higher than GPU2.

And there are a quite number of /device:GPU:0/stream:num... why are they only for GPU0, not one for GPU1, what are they? Is that the reason for imbalance computation between GPU0 and GPU1.